# Two Divs on the same row and center align both of them

Tags: css, html, center

I have two divs like this

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000; float:left">Div 1</div>
<div style="border:1px solid red; float:left">Div 2</div>
```

I want them to display on the same row, so I used `float:left`.

I want both of them to be at center of the page as well, so I tried to wrap them with another div like this

```
<div style="width:100%; margin:0px auto;">
  <div style="border:1px solid #000; float:left">Div 1</div>
  <div style="border:1px solid red; float:left">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. If I change the code to this

```
<div style="width:100%; margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%">
  <div style="border:1px solid #000; float:left">Div 1</div>
  <div style="border:1px solid red; float:left">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

then it's going to the center, but the horizontal scrollbar is there and it seems like it's not really centered as well.

Can you please kindly suggest to me how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Edit: I want the inner div (Div 1 and Div 2) to be center align as well.

Comment: Do you want div1 and div2 to be the same width?

Comment: no, it won't be same width, div 1 will be much smaller

Comment: @Eric I am trying to achieve the same but having both div have the same width and make sure the content of the div does not go over that width. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 60):

You could do this

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #000; display:inline-block;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/MZrym/

1. wrap it in a `div` with `text-align:center;`
2. give the innder `div`s a `display:inline-block;` instead of a `float`

Best also to put that css in a stylesheet.

Comment: To whoever voted down this answer... I don't mind being voted down, but could you share with us why?  It helps me and helps others know why something doesn't work or is inappropriate/

Comment: An additional albeit unasked for way to improve looks is by assigning widths and text-align to the inside divs.  That way you can directly control positioning for multiple elements in the same line if you cannot assign a static width.  eg:  `<div style="width: 20%; text-align: right; display:inline-block">`

Answer (score 10):

Could this do for you? Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azXMN/)

And the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.container {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: auto;   
    width: 304px;
}

div.div1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

div.div2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: if i want to center div 1 and div 2, how can i do it ?

Comment: @knightrider They are centered.. What do you mean? If you want to center the content of div1 and div2 just add `text-align: center;` in the CSS of these two div's.

Comment: This is a bad way of doing it because if the containing div's width changes, or need to be flexible in a particular context, it's either going to break or it's going to require you to recalculate/set the div's widths.

Answer (score 2):

both floated divs need to have a width!

set 50% of width to both and it works.

BTW, the outer div, with its `margin: 0 auto` will only center itself not the ones inside.

Comment: if i want to center inner div as well, how can i do it ?

Comment: @knightrider to center the inner divs, you just need to add widths to the inner divs, and make sure the outer div has a width wide enough! (the border takes space!), please check this example I made: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/6kEsT/

Answer (score 2):

Align to the center, using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`.

```css
.outerdiv
{
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.innerdiv
{
    height:40px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="innerdiv"></div>
    <div class="innerdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Align to the center using `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`

```css
.outerdiv
{
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.innerdiv
{
    height:40px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="innerdiv"></div>
    <div class="innerdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Align to the center vertically and horizontally using `display: flex`, `justify-content: center` and `align-items:center`.

```css
.outerdiv
{
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}

.innerdiv
{
    height:40px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="innerdiv"></div>
    <div class="innerdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would vote against `display: inline-block` since its not supported across browsers, IE < 8 specifically.

```
.wrapper {
    width:500px; /* Adjust to a total width of both .left and .right */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 49%; /* Not 50% because of 1px border. */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 49%; /* Not 50% because of 1px border. */
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Div 1</div>
    <div class="right">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** If no spacing between the cells is desired just change both `.left` and `.right` to use `float: left;`

Comment: instead of having fixed width for wrapper, is there any other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Better way till now:

1. If you give display:inline-block; to inner divs then child elements of inner divs will also get this property and disturb alignment of inner divs.
2. Better way is to use two different classes for inner divs with width, margin and float.

Best way till now:

Use flexbox.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on **flex** it will help you make things right,

on the main div set css `display :flex`

the div's that inside set css: `flex:1 1 auto;`

attached jsfiddle link as example enjoy :)

https://jsfiddle.net/hodca/v1uLsxbg/